# Reason for "suffix or operands invalid for `movq'"?

Tags: python, macos, fortran, gfortran, setup.py

I'm trying to install a python package called `mtspec` which is a wrapper to some Fortran 90 code. (link: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mtspec).  However, this package is rather old (last updated in 2010), and I'm having trouble getting the `setup.py` script to properly compile the code on Mac OSX 10.10.5.  I had to hack the `setup.py` script a little bit myself, due to some apparent changes in `distutils`.  Originally, line 48 in `setup.py` looked like this:

```
from distutils.unixccompiler import UnixCCompiler, _darwin_compiler_fixup
```

which I changed to

```
from distutils.unixccompiler import UnixCCompiler#, _darwin_compiler_fixup
from _osx_support import compiler_fixup as _darwin_compiler_fixup
```

Without this, `setup.py` simply threw the exception `cannot import name _darwin_compiler_fixup`.  I don't know much about `distutils`, so please tell me if that was wrong.  But after the change it at least tries to compile the code.  However, `gfortran` now throws the following errors:

```
/var/folders/vt/9jwlypbs5rz8hy6d_h02pg8xg967kg/T//ccm4Gy5y.s:25:suffix or  operands invalid for `movq'
/var/folders/vt/9jwlypbs5rz8hy6d_h02pg8xg967kg/T//ccm4Gy5y.s:27:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
/var/folders/vt/9jwlypbs5rz8hy6d_h02pg8xg967kg/T//ccm4Gy5y.s:28:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
/var/folders/vt/9jwlypbs5rz8hy6d_h02pg8xg967kg/T//ccm4Gy5y.s:34:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
/var/folders/vt/9jwlypbs5rz8hy6d_h02pg8xg967kg/T//ccm4Gy5y.s:79:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
/var/folders/vt/9jwlypbs5rz8hy6d_h02pg8xg967kg/T//ccm4Gy5y.s:115:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
```

I'm not very experienced with Fortran, so I don't know what this means, and searching on StackOverflow and Google has not turned up any solutions to this problem.  One recommendation I saw on another site (can't remember where I saw this) suggested removing the `-O` compiler flag, but this made the problem worse; the error got thrown even more often.  Running `setup.py` in a `conda` virtual enviornment didn't help either.  I'm at a loss of what to do at this point.  I've installed this packages on Cray Linux and Red Hat Linux before by simple commenting out all the references to Darwin in `setup.py`; it's only Mac that's giving me trouble.

In case it helps, here's the block of code in `setup.py` that configures the compiler:

```
from distutils.unixccompiler import UnixCCompiler#, _darwin_compiler_fixup
from _osx_support import compiler_fixup as _darwin_compiler_fixup
# Monkey patch UnixCCompiler for Unix, Linux and darwin
UnixCCompiler.src_extensions.append(".f90")
def _compile(self, obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts):
        compiler_so = self.compiler_so
        if sys.platform == 'darwin':
            compiler_so = _darwin_compiler_fixup(compiler_so, cc_args + extra_postargs)
        if ext == ".f90":
            if sys.platform == 'darwin' or sys.platform == 'linux2':
                compiler_so = ["gfortran"]
                cc_args = ["-O", "-fPIC", "-c", "-ffree-form"]
        try:
            self.spawn(compiler_so + cc_args + [src, '-o', obj] + extra_postargs)
        except DistutilsExecError, msg:
            raise CompileError, msg
UnixCCompiler._compile = _compile
# set library dir for mac and linux
libs=['gfortran']
```

Comment: Those errors are not Fortran errors, but assembly errors. Notice the suffix `.s` and not `.f90`.

Answer (score 4):

Because you mention that it's only causing trouble on Mac. Could it be that you have macports and homebrew installed on your machine?

I ran into the same error compiling a different library, following link solved it for me: https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/45258

After removing macports (e.g. sudo mv /opt/local ~/macport) everything worked fine.